# pandas iteratively update column values

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, iteration

I have a pandas Series like the following:

`a = pd.Series([a1, a2, a3, a4, ...])`

and I want to create another pandas Series based on the following rule:

`b = pd.Series(a1, a2+a1**0.8, a3 + (a2 + a1**0.8)**0.8, a4 + (a3 + (a2 + a1**0.8)**0.8)**0.8, ...)`.

This is doable using iteration,  but I have a large dataset (millions of records) and I must perform operation for thousands of times (for optimization purposes). I need to do this operation very fast. Is there any possible way for me to realize this by using `pandas` or `numpy` built-in functions?

Comment: Thx. But one crucial difference here is that previous element of b is raised to the power of 0.8, not a multiple of 0.8.

Answer (score 1):

The important point about these kinds of problems that you need to know is that you're on a paradox spot right now. This means that you're on a point that you want to take advantage of both vectorization and non-vectorization like threading or parallelization.

In such situation you can try one/some of the following options:

1. Change the type of your data structure.
2. Rethink your problem and see if it's possible to solve this entirely in a Vectorized way (preferably)
3. Simply use a non-vectorized-based approach but sacrifice something else like memory.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fight against the fundamentally iterative nature of your problem, you could use numba and try to do the easiest performant iterative version you can:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def epow(vec, p):
    out = np.zeros(len(vec))
    out[0] = vec[0]
    for i in range(1, len(vec)):
        out[i] = vec[i] + (out[i-1])**0.8
    return out
```

which gives me

```
In [148]: a1, a2, a3, a4 = range(1, 5)

In [149]: a1, a2+a1**0.8, a3 + (a2 + a1**0.8)**0.8, a4 + (a3 + (a2 + a1**0.8)**0.8)**0.8
Out[149]: (1, 3.0, 5.408224685280692, 7.858724574530816)

In [150]: epow(pd.Series([a1, a2, a3, a4]).values, 0.8)
Out[150]: array([1.        , 3.        , 5.40822469, 7.85872457])
```

and for longer Series:

```
In [151]: s = pd.Series(np.arange(2*10**6))

In [152]: %time epow(s.values, 0.8)
CPU times: user 512 ms, sys: 20 ms, total: 532 ms
Wall time: 531 ms
Out[152]: 
array([0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 3.00000000e+00, ...,
       2.11487244e+06, 2.11487348e+06, 2.11487453e+06])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found if I use @numba.jit, the code runs even slower. Is there any possible explanation for this? I am sorry I am just new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function, it would run in O(log(n)) time

```
def my_func(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        b.append(x[0])
        return x[0]
    element = x[-1]+0.8*my_func(x[:-1])
    b.append(element)
    return element
b= []
my_func(list(a))
```

Comment: I don't think this runs with an efficiency of O(log(N)). It has the efficiency of O(N)

Comment: And it's better to use "for loop" than recursion as recursion involves poping and pushing to the stack and thus has lower efficiency compared to looping.

Comment: Oh! So you mean a single for loop is always better than a recursive function? And in what case is recursion faster than a loop?

Comment: Recursion is always slower than for loop. It must be used only when the problem cant be solved using for loop.

Comment: Regardless of whether if this solution is optimized in terms of runtime or not you should know that recursive function will cost you a lot of memory which means it's not memory efficient. So if that's an issue by OP your fight is literally meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop

```
new_series=[]
cur_val=0
for ele in a:
    cur_val=ele+cur_val**0.8
    new_series.append(cur_val)
```

Comment: @ALollz  Thanks, Updated the answer.

Comment: I don't think so, why?